# Difference between Unit and { }

Tags: kotlin

I think I don't understand what is the diff between `Unit` and `{}`, e.g. when using callback in a fun.

```kotlin
fun x(
    callback: () -> Unit = {} // fine
)

fun x(
    callback: () -> Unit = Unit // not fine
)
```

Comment: Further reading: [Functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#functions) and [Higher-Order Functions and Lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions-and-lambdas).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`{}` is a lambda that returns `Unit`, which is a valid value for `() -> Unit`.

`Unit` is an object, which is not a valid value for `() -> Unit`.

Answer (score 4):

`Unit` is an object with no methods or properties. It's just the default return value for any function. If your function doesn't specify a return type, then that's implicitly returning `Unit`.

`{}` is a lambda function that takes no parameters and - since it's the default - returns `Unit`.